# Vagrant: 'cpu_tlbstate' undeclared

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

`vagrant up` fails on Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.8.0-36-generic

What can I do to fix this?

Here is my current state to debug this:

```
guettli@yoga15:~/projects/yourfirm$ vagrant up
The provider 'virtualbox' that was requested to back the machine
'default' is reporting that it isn't usable on this system. The
reason is shown below:

VirtualBox is complaining that the installation is incomplete. Please
run `VBoxManage --version` to see the error message which should contain
instructions on how to fix this error.
```

```
guettli@yoga15:~/projects/yourfirm$ VBoxManage --version

WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
6.1.10_Ubuntur138449
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350358/how-do-i-resolve-the-character-device-dev-vboxdrv-does-not-exist-error-in-ubu

```
guettli@yoga15:~/projects/yourfirm$ LANG=C sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms 

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.10
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.10 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-36-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-36-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/virtualbox-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log for more information.
```

```
guettli@yoga15:~/projects/yourfirm$ cat /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/make.log
DKMS make.log for virtualbox-6.1.10 for kernel 5.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Mon Jan 11 11:50:25 CET 2021
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrv.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvGip.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvSem.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvTracer.o
In file included from ./include/asm-generic/percpu.h:7,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h:556,
                 from ./arch/x86/include/asm/preempt.h:6,
                 from ./include/linux/preempt.h:78,
                 from ./include/linux/spinlock.h:51,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/../SUPDrvInternal.h:79,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:32:
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c: In function 'supdrvOSChangeCR4':
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:38: error: 'cpu_tlbstate' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'cpuhp_state'?
  760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:318:9: note: in definition of macro '__pcpu_size_call_return'
  318 |  typeof(variable) pscr_ret__;     \
      |         ^~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:24: note: in expansion of macro 'this_cpu_read'
  760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:38: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
      |                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/linux/percpu-defs.h:318:9: note: in definition of macro '__pcpu_size_call_return'
  318 |  typeof(variable) pscr_ret__;     \
      |         ^~~~~~~~
/var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c:760:24: note: in expansion of macro 'this_cpu_read'
  760 |     RTCCUINTREG uOld = this_cpu_read(cpu_tlbstate.cr4);
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:290: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:519: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build/vboxdrv] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:1780: /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/6.1.10/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.8.0-36-generic'
```

https://www.google.com/search?q=%27cpu_tlbstate%27+undeclared

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/19644

The packages are all up-to-date:

```
guettli@yoga15:~/projects/yourfirm$ dpkg -l virtualbox
ii  virtualbox     6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - base binaries

guettli@yoga15:~/projects/yourfirm$ dpkg -l virtualbox-dkms
ii  virtualbox-dkms 6.1.10-dfsg-1~ubuntu1.20.04.1 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - kernel module sources for dkms
```

AFAIK Virtualbox 6.1.16 would solve this, but this is not available yet:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=virtualbox

Comment: It looks to be a VM issue that you already have put a ticket in with the mfg. I do not see this as a Ubuntu issue, you also do not say what version of Ubuntu this is.

Comment: @David I use Ubuntu 20.04. I heard that VirtualBox 6.1.16 works. The question is now: Why does Ubuntu provide 6.1.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Virtualbox 6.1.16 from the Oracle repository, see the section "Debian-based Linux distributions" on the [Virtualbox site](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

A more straight-forward guide is [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-virtualbox-on-ubuntu-20-04/#installing-virtualbox-from-oracle-repositories).

Comment: Virtualbox 6.1.16 is now available in [focal-updates](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal-updates/virtualbox) and now everything works again. No need to use the Oracle repo any more. Thank you.